# How to read a JSON file using nods.js line by line

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

Given I have a **data.json** file of the format

`{"name": "Jack", "user": "1" }
 {"name": "Adam", "user": "2" }
 {"name": "Nick", "user": "3" }
 {"name": "Sam" , "user": "4" }`

How do I read this using JSON.parse and output the data on to the console ?

My code is as follows :

```
require('fs').readFile('./data.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    console.log("-- Start file -- ");
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data.user);
    console.log(data.name);
    console.log("-- End file -- ");
});
```

Comment: You JSON is invalid.

Comment: You are looking for `obj.user` and `obj.name`.

Comment: If it is of this particular format, is there a way to parse it in any manner?

Comment: Have you done `console.log(data)` yet to see exactly what the data looks like?

Comment: @Sam : Yes I did try that. It prints all the data to the console. I was trying to parse the individual elements

Comment: @MinusFour : Thanks for that. Using obj[0].user gave me the individual records. Earlier I thought parse would go through all the records which wasn't the case

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid JSON if it's not wrapped around in an array

If you do have access, use Comptonburger's solution. Otherwise, you can use this:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  var jsonLine = JSON.parse(line);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the structure of the file **data.json**? Just wrap your objects in an array.

```
[
    {"name": "Jack", "user": "1"},
    ...
]
```

Comment: I did try wrapping the JSON in an array. It gives this output `-- Start file --
undefined
undefined
-- End file --`

Answer (score -2):

```
var contents = fs.readFileSync("jsoncontent.json");
// Define to JSON type
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
```